# Is there any scriptable way to delete a GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I am looking for options to delete a GH repository within my script.

AFAIK, GitHub CLI does not delete a GitHub repository.

What are my options to delete a GitHub repository in a script (like shell, bash, python etc...)

Comment: Elsewhere you mentioned that you don't want to use REST: how do you expect to manipulate a remote repository without some remote API calls? And REST calls can easily be scripted in any of the languages you mention.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, I know everything will be REST or rpc behind the scene. I am hoping to find a command line, or git command to delete. If there is no other option, then I do what I have to do and will use REST - when no other choice.